# setAnimationDidStopSelector @selector not running method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have used this previously in my app, and having looked over everything I cannot find the difference, but for some reason when I run:

```
-(void)moveSelectorToDisplayPosition:(id)sender{

    int givenTag = [sender tag];
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [displayedSelections objectAtIndex:givenTag];



    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    tempImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(tempImageView.frame, 30 - tempImageView.frame.origin.x,  240 - tempImageView.frame.origin.y);
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(loadInTextForSelectedTool:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

`loadInTextForSelectedTool` does not get called and I cannot figure out why. No errors or anything.

This is the method I'm trying to run, could anyone let me know if they see anything amiss or maybe something I might have forgotten? I tried also setting the `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:tempImageView];` but no luck :(.

`-(void)loadInTextForSelectedTool:(id)sender;`

Thanks.

Comment: But the animation runs fine, correct?

Comment: Yes it does, so im not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the delegate to the controller that implements `loadInTextForSelectedTool:`

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
```

Also, according to the documentation, the selector should have the following form:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

And finally, Apple discourages the use of this animation method in iOS 4.0 or later:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Comment: Maybe I'm a little confused on this, but why do i have to include that method? If i just want to call my own custom method when the animation is finished? Also I have an exact working copy of my code else where and I do not do either of those... any ideas why that is working?

Comment: Well, it might work this way, but the documentation states that should be the form of the selector: "The message sent to the animation delegate after animations end. The default value is NULL. The selector should be of the form: - (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context.",  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: I'm looking into animation blocks right now. thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah that would probably be the best solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to run on 3.2 or earlier, you should be using block animations. They really simplify specifying what to do at the end of an animation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1